# Можно ли сделать свой картинку частицами через particles.js?

Tags: javascript

Можно ли через библиотеку [particles.js](https://vincentgarreau.com/particles.js/) сгенерировать узор по схеме?

Например так: 
Где 1 это частица, а 0 ее отсутствие.

```
let map = [
            "0", "0", "1", "1", "0", "0", "0",
            "0", "1", "1", "1", "1", "0", "0",
            "1", "0", "1", "1", "0", "1", "0",
            "1", "0", "1", "1", "0", "1", "0",
            "0", "1", "1", "1", "1", "0", "0",
            "0", "0", "1", "1", "0", "0", "0"
          ];
```

Comment: Как вы себе это представляете? о_О

Comment: интересно-интересно

Comment: эта библиотека нужна для анимации, Вы хотите статический рисунок? в целом на основе Ваших входных данных можно построить узор из точек =)